# Why won't XCOPY work with my script?

Tags: windows, batch

I am making a simple tool that will back up some save files for some of my games. Some of the games have multiple files within a folder, and I would like to copy the target folder to a new location with a new name, but I can't get it to work right. I can do this with individual files with `COPY` and `XCOPY`, but the same doesn't seem to work with folders. Here is what I'm working with:

```
XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\EA Games\Dead Space" ".\Save Backup"
XCOPY "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Visceral\Dead Space" ".\Settings Backup"
```

I have used sources like the [documentation on SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) but none of the commands work either. I've used `/s` and `/t` as well as others, but they don't do anything. How do I copy a folder to a new location *and* rename it in the new location.

Comment: well, the second line has quote issues. xcopy batches individual items and transfers them so you definitely want to use `/e` so that it recurses into the source directory. I'd confirm that your destination exists and the .\ resolves as expected, and play around with trailing \ on the source and dest. finally since this is a large copy, consider robocopy instead.

Comment: and certianly paste all those paths into a `cd` to make sure they actually exist. Saves usually store in Documents\My Games\publisher\game\... and LocalAppData may or may not be the correct AppData\ subdirectory. also the doublequotes may interfer with the env var expansion.

Comment: The quote issue was a post mistake, and is absent in my script. I'm using .\ intentionally to copy the folders to the script's working directory. I have also confirmed the folder locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I copy a folder to a new location and rename it in the new location?

I would try including the `/E`, `/I` and `/Y` options e.g.:

```
XCOPY /E /I /Y "%USERPROFILE%\EA Games\Dead Space" ".\Save Backup"
XCOPY /E /I /Y "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Visceral\Dead Space" ".\Settings Backup"
```

In order (from [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)):

- `/E` copies folders and subfolders, including empty folders (on the off-chance there are no saves or settings files).
- `/I` instructs `XCOPY` to always assume the destination is a folder (this is useful when the destination does not exist).
- `/Y` suppresses any prompt to confirm overwriting a file (useful if you are overwriting existing files/folders).

You may also want to consider `/C`, which will continue copying even if an error occurs. Since you indicated you have tried "other" `XCOPY` options, you may wish to include extra details if you run (or have run) into problems with these particular ones.

On a side note, as suggested in comments, I would verify the actual locations of the files you wish to copy. Currently, the [PC Gaming Wiki for Deadspace](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Dead_Space) lists these as `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Electronic Arts\Dead Space` for saves and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Electronic Arts\Dead Space\` for settings. So:

```
XCOPY /E /I /Y "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Electronic Arts\Dead Space" ".\Save Backup"
XCOPY /E /I /Y "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Electronic Arts\Dead Space" ".\Settings Backup"
```

Comment: I have tried using the additional commands you suggested, but this does not seem to work. I used `CD` in combination with `CD..` to switch between the two locations, but this also seems to have no effect.

Comment: Here is my new script:
`CD "%USERPROFILE%\EA Games"
XCOPY /E /I /Y "Dead Space" ".\Save Backup"
CD..
CD "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Visceral"
XCOPY /E /I /Y "Dead Space" ".\Settings Backup"
CD..`
I have modified the folder paths, so the ones listed are correct.

Comment: `CD..` seems redundant in your new script (unless there is something specific you are trying to do?). Also, to confirm, are you expecting to see the new backup folders created in the same directory as the one you run the script in? Because as-is, with the ".\" notation, they would be created as `%USERPROFILE%\EA GamesSave Backup` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Visceral\Settings Backup`, respectively. You may also want to explain exactly how the command fails (i.e. what it does or doesn't do or what you want it to do) since I think I am still a bit confused about.. =P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Windows Vista or higher, you should consider using [Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead of XCOPY.  The syntax is a little different, but it's designed to work on directories.  Your particular use case is perfect for the /mir switch.  The benefit of that is that you get a true mirror copy of the oringinal directory - that is, files that no longer exist in the source are deleted at the destination.  It also is smart enough to skip files that have not changed since the previous run.

Your syntax would simply be

```
Robocopy "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Electronic Arts\Dead Space" ".\Settings Backup" /mir
Robocopy "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Visceral\Dead Space" ".\Settings Backup" /mir
```